# Convert string into key-value pairs in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string:

```
var rrule = "DTSTART=20190514T111500Z;FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1";
```

I want to convert this string to key-> value pairs in an array.

```
[
  dtstart: 20190514T111500Z, 
  freq: daily,
  interval: 1
]
```

I know I can take the string and split it based on  the semicolon:

```
var array = rrule.split(";");
```

... but this leaves me with an array like this:

```
[
  "DTSTART=20190514T111500Z",
  "FREQ=DAILY",
  "INTERVAL=1"
]
```

I guess I need another step to map out the keys/values, but I get lost at this point.

Ideally, for the string I want to be able to easily access what dtstarts equals, what interval equals, what other variables equal and so on.

Comment: You want to turn it into an array or an object? Your desired "array" is invalid

Comment: So Arrays don't have user defined keys. You might want to have convert to an object. Like 
{  
    dtstart: 2019....,
    .... 
}

Comment: Use a second string split and you have it: `rrule.split(";").map(function (str) {return str.split("=")})`

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, I would want to convert it to an object like { dtstart: 2019...., .... }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
let str = "DTSTART=20190514T111500Z;FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1";

let obj = {};
for (let entry of str.split(";")) {
  let pair = entry.split("=");
  obj[pair[0]] = pair[1];
}

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: I'd suggest using [destruction assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) `let [key, value] = entry.split("=")` which makes the result look a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You already know how to split on the `;` to get an array, from there you can just aggregate (using `reduce`) to get an object:

```js
var rrule = "DTSTART=20190514T111500Z;FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1";

var result = rrule.split(";").reduce( (obj,item) => {
   let [key,value] = item.split("=");
   obj[key] = value;
   return obj;
},{});

console.log(result["DTSTART"])
console.log(result["FREQ"])
console.log(result["INTERVAL"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like the code below:

```js
var rrule = "DTSTART=20190514T111500Z;FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1";
let finalObj = {};
rrule.split(';').forEach(i => finalObj[i.split('=')[0]] = i.split('=')[1]);
console.log('finalObj',finalObj);
```

Here I'm first splitting with ';' so consider the first item to be `DTSTART=20190514T111500Z` Then on splitting with `=` I get  `finalObject['DTSTART'] = 20190514T111500Z`

Answer (score 0):

You were correct to start with split first, this would then return you an array of strings.

To easily convert them, just use `map`, to return the split the single strings once more, and then return an object based on the property name you would like to give it and it's value

```js
function createKeyValuePairFromString( str ) {
  return str.split(';').map( item => {
    const splitted = item.split('=');
    return { [splitted[0]]: splitted[1] };
  });
}

console.log( createKeyValuePairFromString("DTSTART=20190514T111500Z;FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1") );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array created and split it again with =

```js
function convertToObject(cookieString) {
  const cookieObj = {};
  if (!cookieString && typeof cookieString !== 'string') return cookieObj;

  const arr = cookieString.split(';');
  arr.forEach(record => {
    if (record.includes('=')) {
      const [key, value] = record.split('=');
      cookieObj[key.trim()] = value;
    }
  });
  return cookieObj;
}
```

Comment: jest test
```js
expect(convertToObject()).toEqual({});
expect(convertToObject('')).toEqual({});
expect(convertToObject('key1=value1')).toEqual({ key1: 'value1' });
expect(convertToObject('key1=value1;key2=value2;')).toEqual({
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 'value2',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using forEach()**

```js
let str = "DTSTART=20190514T111500Z;FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1";

let obj = {};

let strArr = str.split(';')

strArr.forEach((str) => {
  let [key, value] = str.split('=')
  obj[key] = value;
});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly simple version, returning an object, not an array:

```js
const toObj = str => str
  .split (';')
  .map ( s => s .split ('=') )
  .reduce ( (a, [k, v]) => ({...a, [k]: v}), {} )

let str = "DTSTART=20190514T111500Z;FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1";

console.log (
  toObj(str)
)
```

One of the reasons I like the library is that we can write this sort of logic more simply.  In [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/) (disclaimer: I'm one of the authors), it might look like this:

```js
const toObj = pipe ( split (';'), map (split ('=') ), fromPairs)

let str = "DTSTART=20190514T111500Z;FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1";

console.log (
  toObj(str)
)
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/ramda@0.26.1"></script><script>
const {pipe, split, map, fromPairs} = ramda;               </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "DTSTART=20190514T111500Z;FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1";
```

// string splitting rule

```
const rule = (string, delimiter) => string.split(delimiter);

const result = rule(str, ';').reduce((acc, s) => {
  const [key, value] = rule(s, '=');
  acc[key] = value;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```